# Wordpress Setting API data retrieve problem

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am developing wordpress plugin using setting API. I was save the data but cant retrieve the data using this "get_option('pizz_text_field_discount');". I think that is problem but where is problem i cant find out this.

```
    function pizz_settings_init(  ) { 
    
            register_setting( 'pizz_pluginPage', 'pizz_settings' );
    
            add_settings_section(
                'pizz_pluginPage', 
                __( '', 'PizzaPOOL' ), 
                'pizz_settings_section', 
                'pizz_pluginPage'
            );
    
            add_settings_field( 
                'pizz_text_field_discount', 
                __( 'Discount Percent', 'PizzaPOOL' ), 
                'pizz_text_field_0_render', 
                'pizz_pluginPage', 
                'pizz_pluginPage' 
            );
    }

function discount_based_on_cart_total( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $cart_total = $cart_object->cart_contents_total; // Cart total

    $percent = get_option('pizz_text_field_discount');
   
    $discount = $cart_total * $percent / 100; 
    
    $cart_object->add_fee( "Discount ($percent%)", -$discount, true );
    
}
```

Comment: Check your DB and make sure that option actually exists and has a value. Easy way to confirm if it is or isn't there.

Comment: @MarkTruitt I used this "get_option('pizz_text_field_discount')" . but dont value dont pass.